# Joomla - Contact Form - Miscellaneous info above form

Tags: forms, joomla

I want to add a ***new contact form*** with some extra information.

- The *first screenshot* shows that I can add: 'miscellaneous info'
- The *second screenshot* shows the result: This info is at the bottom of the contact form.

**Can this 'miscellaneous info' be put at the top of a contact form?**

[image: Add a new contact]

[image: Presentation of this contact]

Comment: I'm very confused here. What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: Lodder: I have updated my question with screenshots and better text. I hope this makes more sence? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to do that first of all you need to create a template override of contact form.

To do so:

1. Open your template folder and create **html** folder if it doesn't exist
2. In **html** folder create folder **com_contact** if it doesn't exist
3. In **com_contact** folder create folder **contact**
4. Copy **/components/com_contact/views/contact/tmpl/default.php** file to **/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/com_contact/contact/default.php**
5. Open your newly copied **default.php file** find the following line anywhere you want (after or before another elements):

   echo $this->contact->misc;

Note, in some templates you might already have **/templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/html/com_contact/contact/default.php** file. Then you just need to customize it for your needs.

Comment: Is it going to be a parameter? I think you can remove `&& $this->params->get('show_misc')`

Comment: Yes you can remove all parameters, the main line you actually need is: <?php echo $this->contact->misc; ?>, edited answer, thanks Lodder.